# Hadoop Map reduce program on multinode cluster

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a query on Hadoop Map reduce. We have 3 clusters with each cluster having 5 nodes. Now if i written a Map Reduce program & want to run it to process data on all 3 clusters. Do i need to run this Map reduce program on 1 node only or do i need to run map reduce program  on all nodes ?  Finally it needs to process all the data on my 3 clusters.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to run your MR program only one node, MR framework will execute it in all slave nodes in the cluster.

One advantage of MR framework is that execution is based on data locality, Computation moves to nodes where data present. Since you have 3 clusters, for getting good performance it is always better to deploy or run your application on all these three cluster.

Processing data of these 3 cluster in 1 cluster is also possible, provided your clusters are in the same network. You should not do this, as it degrades the performance. Data in other cluster(s) need to bring to the cluster where actual execution happens. This can be achieved using HDFS URI

```
Eg : Cluster A hdfs URI : hdfs://nnhost-clusterA:8020/inputfile
     Cluster B HDFS URI : hdfs://nnhost-clusterB:8020/input
```

From cluster C you may access data in the above two clusters A&B by giving full HDFS URI.